# Python-Telegram-Bot: How to wait for user input after clicking on InlineKeyboardButton

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm working on a bot with the Python-Telegram-Bot API. Right now I'm updating the bot menu with InlineKeyboardButtons instead of `?menu`, `?info` type of commands (like on Discord). But I came across some trouble. Let me explain step by step what the command is supposed to do:

**Step 1** - User opens up the menu (a commandhandler)

**Step 2** - `InlineKeyboardButtons` load, one of them has an option called "Jokenpo" for the game

**Step 3** - I set its `callback_data` to load a message greeting the player and showing the rules (`def jkpMenu`).

**Step 4** - Then `def jkpMenu` is supposed to go to the next state, that is `def jokenpo`. During the function, there's a loop for receiving input like `paper`, `rock`, `scissors` that keeps repeting until user types `stop` or loses their lives.

```
varScore = 0
varLives = 5
varTie = 0
JKP = range(2)

...

def menuTest(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> int:
    commands = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text=' | Changelog',  callback_data='clog'), InlineKeyboardButton(text=' | Info',  callback_data='info')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text=' | Jokenpo',  callback_data='jokenpo')]]
    update.message.reply_text("Menu:\n", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(commands))

def comQuery(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    if query.data == 'clog':        changelog(update, context)
    if query.data == 'info':        myInfo(update, context) 
    if query.data == 'jokenpo':     jkpMenu(update, context)

#Jokenpo 1: greetings and rules
def jkpMenu(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) ->JKP:
    update.callback_query.message.reply_text('Jokenpo mode. Please type "rock", "paper" or "scissors" to continue')
    return JKP

#Jokenpo 2: 
def jokenpo(update: Update, _:CallbackContext):
    msgUser = update.callback_query.message.text.lower()
    global varScore
    global varLives
    global varTie
    while True:
        computer = ("rock", "paper", "scissors")
        computer = random.choice(computer)
        if (msgUser== "rock" and computer == "paper") or (msgUser== "paper" and computer == "scissors") or (msgUser=="scissors" and computer == "rock"):
            update.callback_query.message.reply_text("Computer chooses <i>" + computer + "</i>. <b>You lose!</b>", parse_mode ='HTML')
            varLives -= 1
        if (msgUser== "rock" and computer == "scissors") or (msgUser == "paper" and computer == "rock") or (msgUser == "scissors" and computer == "paper"):
            update.callback_query.message.reply_text("Computer chooses <i>" + computer + "</i>. <b>You win!</b>", parse_mode ='HTML')
            varScore +=1
        if (msgUser== computer):
            update.callback_query.message.reply_text("We both chose <i>" + computer +"</i>. <b>It's a tie!</b>", parse_mode ='HTML')
            varTie +=1
        if (msgUser== "status"):
            update.callback_query.message.reply_text("Your current score: " + str(varScore) + " points.\nYou have "+ str(varLives)+ " lives left.\nWe tied " + str(varTie) +' times.')
        if (msgUser== "sair") or (varLives == 0):
            update.callback_query.message.reply_text("Game finished. You made <b>" + str(varScore) + "</b> points.\nWe tied " + str(varTie) +' times.\n', parse_mode ='HTML')
            varScore = 0
            varTie = 0
            varLives = 5
            return ConversationHandler.END
        update.callback_query.message.reply_text('Please choose: paper, rock or scissors? ')
        return

...
...

def(main):
convHandler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[jokenpo],
        fallbacks=[],
        states = {
            JKP: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, jokenpo)]
        })
    dp.add_handler(convHandler)
```

Problem is: I managed to do that before, when I used CommandHandlers to access the function and it worked.
But now it only reaches the first function (Step 3), it seems it doesn't return to the state I wanted. When I changed `return JKP` for `return jokenpo(update,_)` it did access `def jokenpo`, but it didn't wait for any answer.

When I set the inline buttons, since they use CallbackContext, I'm confused on how to handle arguments.

I copied only some part of the code, not it complete, since the other parts are related to other functions. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues in your code snippet & description:

1. using `global` variables is in general bad practice. If you want to store user/chat related data, I suggest to use PTBs built-in mechanism for that. see [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Storing-bot,-user-and-chat-related-data).
2. The `while True` loop in `jokenpo` doesn't make any sense. In fact, at the end of the body of the loop, you `return` anyway, so the body is executed exactly once.
3. As entry points for your conversation you use `entry_points = [jokenpo]`, but `jokenpo` is a function and not a handler
4. In the state `JKP` you have a handler `MessageHandler(Filters.text, jokenpo)`. This means that the `update` that will be passed to `jokenpo` will have `update.(edited_)message/channel_post`, but never `update.callback_query` - yet you try to access this attribute within `jokenpo`.
5. "Then `def jkpMenu` is supposed to go to the next state, that is `def jokenpo`" - the callback `jkpMenu` is not part of your `ConversationHandler` at all and hence the return value will be ignored completely.
6. "When I changed `return JKP` for `return jokenpo(update,_)` it did access `def jokenpo`, but it didn't wait for any answer." Sure - you *called* the function. But waiting for input can only work if the conversationhandler is started, which this doesn't do
7. "When I set the inline buttons, since they use CallbackContext, I'm confused on how to handle arguments." This one I just don't understand. What do you mean by "arguments" in the context of inline buttons and what does that have to do with `CallbackContext`?

I have the impression that you need to deepen your understanding of how PTB is supposed to be used, especially `ConversationHandler`. I suggest to have a look at the introductory [example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#conversationbotpy). Following the flow chart & tracking the executed code while running the example should help to get a better understanding of what's going on. Also reading the documentation of [`ConversationHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html) should clarify some things.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Also for completeness sake: This was already discussed to some extend in the usergroup of PTB, see https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/513856